# While implementing Spring OAuth2 2.0 in REST services I am getting exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Spring OAuth2 version 2.0.7 with my REST web services.

But my code won't compile because of this exception.

```
Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler] for bean with name 'userApprovalHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler
```

Cannot find class
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler

It was there in older version of Spring.

Comment: You'll need to redo the configuration if you are upgrading from 1 to 2 (which I guess you are?).  If you do a search you will find some other questions on SO already mentioning this error.

Comment: You know the solution?

Comment: There isn't a specific solution to your question. The point is that there are major changes between version 1 and 2 (including the fact that that class no longer  exists). You will find the same question asked already (with some answers), so you should look at those. Search for the class name.